# Handlebars - replace {{x}} syntax by <%x%> or similar

Tags: templates, jsp-tags, ember.js, mustache, handlebars.js

I have found interesting [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) framework which uses [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for view templates. However, my server-side templating language [Latte](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating) forbids typing `{{variable}}` to the HTML pages. Is there any way to set up handlebars to use different sign, for example `<%variable%>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question as I think that is not possible, but you don't have to include any handlebars in the html. You can put all ember html in handlebar files and then have them precompiled when files are edited and saved (which converts them to javascript). From there you can serve them up as javascript and append these views client side.

http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Depending on your editor/os there are plenty of tools out there that can watch a directory and execute scripts when files are modified. This practice is used quite a bit for coffeescript as well.

It is also possible to use ember without handlebars, but you do lose bindings.